# Event server for .net

Tags: c#, .net, events, windows-services, ipc

I've a winform app that is connected to a sql server database and there are many pc client with the application installed. A standard desktop client/server application.
I want that a single client can communicate with all others, for example I want the administrator cand send a message to all clients. Something like SignalR fir asp.net.
I do not want that is the client that ask to database if there are messages, I want that all clients connects to a service that raise events like broadcast message or chat.

I prefer not to install something that needs a web server, but I will consider all your suggestions. Also I'd like to know if there is a specific name to this functionality so I can do a more accurate search.

thanks to all

Comment: You could use a UDP, whenever there is a new message u simply broadcast it in the network ( im assuming its on a LAN enviroment, if not you can send to the ip's you need to also but its a bit more tricky). Then the clients rise an event for each message they get

Comment: You could go for SignalR, it works for desktop apps as well. See [this repo](https://github.com/Expecho/Self-Hosted-SignalR)